# ArcGIS JSON export for offline map

Tags: json, arcgis

I've been provided a JSON export from ArcGIS. All the data works as expected but I need this to work locally and offline (Windows), I understand that it will need a local server such as Laragon to process the JSON data but I'm struggling to find any existing examples.

I don't have a Codepen or any code to share I'm afraid, I'm just seeking advice as to whether this is possible.

Here is a sample of the JSON file...

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":0,"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[0.31333230810856183,51.318941963011767]},"properties":{"FID":0,"Easting":561300,"Northing":160300,"Gallery_De":"Incomplete copper alloy harness link."}},{"type":"Feature","id":1,"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[0.3137235953822976,51.312458960687728]},"properties":{"FID":1,"Easting":561350,"Northing":159580,"Gallery_De":"Cemetery with grave goods including coins, brooches, beads, spearheads, rings, a pendant and knife."}},{"type":"Feature","id":2,"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[0.32136286036320083,51.307442288983943]},"properties":
```

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. You need to server that json from a local dev server?